# Use array as jQuery POST Variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, http-post

When sending data via POST or GET with jQuery you use for format `{ name:"value" }` so I thought, is there a way to do it with this kind of code:

```
var postdata = array();
postdata['name'] = "data";
$.post("page.php", postdata, function(data)
{
    alert(data);
}
```

I tried this, and it doesn't seem to work. Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to initialize is an object, not an array. You can initialize objects in two ways:

```
var postdata = {};
```

Or:

```
var postdata = new Object();
```

Then you can assign keys and values just like you intended:

```
postdata['name'] = "data";
```

Or:

```
postdata.name = "data";
```

You can also build your object in the initialization phase:

```
postdata = {
    name: "data"
}
```

Comment: ahhh! haha i forgot to close the `});` with `);` with the previous IF statement :) sorry, works now :D:D